# Liquibase: receiving "file does not exist" exception when file exists for changelog.xml

Tags: java, mule, liquibase

I am attempting to implement a java triggered liquibase database update.

I have the following code:

```
java.sql.Connection connection = openConnection(eventContext); 
Database database = DatabaseFactory.getInstance().findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(new JdbcConnection(connection));
String changelog = UpgradePanDatabase.class.getResource("/liquibase/db.changelog.xml").getPath();
Liquibase liquibase = new liquibase.Liquibase(changelog, new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor(), database);
liquibase.update(new Contexts(), new LabelExpression());
connection.close();
```

but I receive the following ChangeLogParseException:

> /Users/ntregillus/myApp/.mule/apps/myApp/classes/liquibase/db.changelog.xml does not exist

But I know the file exists, I can copy the path, and open it directly from the terminal, and also find it within the File Explorer. Why is Liquibase not able to find this file?

Comment: for full disclosure, I am running this code within a mule component on deployment

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most likely cause is that the changelog is not being packaged as a resource in the jar file. Check the structure of the packaged jar rather than your local developer working copy.

Comment: this was the case. the file was not getting included in the jar

Answer (score 0):

UpgradePanDatabase.class.getResource("/liquibase/db.changelog.xml")

It will Search it wrt to "UpgradePanDatabase".class

Check if 
Absolute_path_of_FolderContaing_UpgradePanDatabase.class + /liquibase/db.changelog.xml> is same as in your IDE.

But in your case, it should be Wrt to "classes" Folder
Try to debug -using SOP- what does "String changelog" say. That might help.